# Arbitrary and consistent change of array values for no apparent reason in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, dereference

The code below generates a 3x3 matrix with random integer values between 1-9. The matrix is generated in the initSquare function and is printed in the printSquare function, but for some unknown reason, the value of the bottom left value (*mptr[2][0]) always changes to the value 2, regardless of is previous value.

Below is an output from printing the elements of the filled matrix in a line from the initSquare function, and below it is the mysteriously altered square as it prints from printSquare. Notice the change of the element from 3 to 2. This happens with every generation of the square, with that particular element always being changed to 2.

Help in this matter is much appreciated.

421695378

4   2   1
6   9   5
2   7   8

```
void initSquare(MagSquare_PTR mptr, int magicsquaresize){
int i, j, m, randomNum, numSquares;
numSquares = (magicsquaresize * magicsquaresize);
int check[numSquares][2];
for(m = 0; m < numSquares; m++){
    check[m][0] = m;
    check[m][1] = 0;
}

for( i = 0; i < magicsquaresize; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < magicsquaresize; j++){
        randomNum = ((rand()%numSquares) + 1);
        while(check[randomNum-1][1] == 1){
            randomNum = ((rand()%numSquares) + 1);
        }
        check[randomNum-1][1] = 1;
        *mptr[i][j] = randomNum;
        printf("%d", *mptr[i][j]); //test

    }
}
```

}

```
void printSquare(MagSquare_PTR mptr, int magicsquaresize){
int i, j;
printf("\n");
for(i = 0; i < magicsquaresize; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < magicsquaresize; j++){
        printf("%d   " , *mptr[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Are you aware that in `*mptr[i][j]`, the `[]` bind more strongly than the prefix `*`? Is this what you want? It would appear that you want to dereference the pointer first, then access indexed elements using `[]`, so it should be `(*mptr)[i][j]`.

Comment: can you tell me definition of MagSquare_PTR ?

Comment: @FelixFrank
works
Thanks a lot